# (!) Some chunks are larger than 500 KiB after minification

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, yarn-workspaces

On rRun `yarn dev` it work fine but whenI run `yarn build` it's showing this error

```
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
Done in 6.03s.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After adding this on **vite.config.js** its fixed

```
build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output:{
                manualChunks(id) {
                    if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                        return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Full FIle is like

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        i18n(),
    ],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'),

        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output:{
                manualChunks(id) {
                    if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                        return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using MUI and am still getting the warning. 

build/assets/@mui-9a782d5f.js   738.47 kB

A workaround to get the warning away (not fix), add this to build object in config file:

` chunkSizeWarningLimit: 800,`

Comment: those are warnings, and accepted answer does not explain how it helps to minimize chunks